# Retrieve the client certificates from Cloud SQL using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

In order to enforce SSL connections, we specify `require_ssl = "true"` under the `settings.ip_configuration` block.
We can get the server certificates as such:

```
output "servercertificate" {
    value = "${google_sql_database_instance.master.server_ca_cert.0.cert}"
}
```

How do we get/specify the client certificates and the client key for an instance?

Comment: So as it turns out, the current version of the google provider i.e. v1.19.1 does not yet support this feature. The [pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/2290/files) has been merged which will allow this functionality.
Check [this](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/blob/2.0.0/website/docs/r/sql_ssl_cert.html.markdown) for more details on how to use.
This feature can be used on building the provider from source and placing it in the terraform plugin folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With release [1.20.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/v1.20.0/CHANGELOG.md), one can retreive client certificates using the `google_sql_ssl_cert` resource. Here is an example showcasing how to use it:

```
resource "google_sql_ssl_cert" "client_cert" {
    depends_on  = ["google_sql_database_instance.master", "google_sql_database.database", "google_sql_user.user"]
    common_name = "terraform-generated"
    instance    = "${google_sql_database_instance.master.name}"
}
```

The attributes associated with this resource are outlined [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/blob/2.0.0/website/docs/r/sql_ssl_cert.html.markdown)

In order to use the latest terraform provider run `terraform init -upgrade`